# Responsive design image and text issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to build a responsive web page where once the user switch the view from desktop to mobile to be able to see mobile version where the categories will be placed one on side rather than 6 on a line. It is working up to certain pixels and it works on landscape mode but in portrait it seems that everything is overlaying. Here is my code:

```
    <code>
<style type="text/css">.catalogue{padding:0; margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;}
@media all and(min-device-width: 769px)and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)  {

}
.catalogueItems{display:inline-block;width:16%;}
.catalogueItemsText{width: 175px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(229, 19, 39);}

}


@media all and(max-width: 480px)  {
.catalogueItems {  width:51%;}
.catalogueItemsText { width:51%;}}

@media all and (min-width: 481px)and (max-width: 768px){.catalogueItems { display:inline-block; width:60%;}
}


</style>
</code>
<div class="catalogue">
<div class="catalogueItems"><code><code><a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a></code> </code>
<div class="catalogueItemsText"><code><span style="font-size:16px;"><code><font color="#ffffff"><span style="line-height: 22.3999996185303px;">Bed Frames</span></font></code></span> </code></div>
<code> </code></div>

<div class="catalogueItems"><code><code><a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a></code> </code>

<div class="catalogueItemsText"><code><span style="font-size:16px;"><code><font color="#ffffff"><span style="line-height: 22.3999996185303px;">Bed Frames</span></font></code></span> </code></div>
<code> </code></div>

<div class="catalogueItems"><code><code><a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a></code> </code>

<div class="catalogueItemsText"><code><span style="font-size:16px;"><code><font color="#ffffff"><span style="line-height: 22.3999996185303px;">Bed Frames</span></font></code></span> </code></div>
<code> </code></div>

<div class="catalogueItems"><code><code><a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a></code> </code>

<div class="catalogueItemsText"><code><span style="font-size:16px;"><code><font color="#ffffff"><span style="line-height: 22.3999996185303px;">Bed Frames</span></font></code></span> </code></div>
<code> </code></div>

<div class="catalogueItems"><code><code><a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a></code> </code>

<div class="catalogueItemsText"><code><span style="font-size:16px;"><code><font color="#ffffff"><span style="line-height: 22.3999996185303px;">Bed Frames</span></font></code></span> </code></div>
<code> </code></div>

<div class="catalogueItems"><code><code><a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a></code> </code>

<div class="catalogueItemsText"><code><span style="font-size:16px;"><code><font color="#ffffff"><span style="line-height: 22.3999996185303px;">Bed Frames</span></font></code></span> </code></div>
<code> </code></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little bit complicated. I think it can be much simpler.

Here is an example, it doesn't do it exactly how you want but it could be a good start :

Fiddle to test it :
http://jsfiddle.net/y9eo177w/1/

HTML part :

```
<div class="catalogue">
    <div class="catalogueItems">
        <a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a> 
        <div class="catalogueItemsText">Bed Frames</div>
    </div>
    <div class="catalogueItems">
        <a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a> 
        <div class="catalogueItemsText">Bed Frames</div>
    </div>
    <div class="catalogueItems">
        <a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a> 
        <div class="catalogueItemsText">Bed Frames</div>
    </div>
    <div class="catalogueItems">
        <a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a> 
        <div class="catalogueItemsText">Bed Frames</div>
    </div>
    <div class="catalogueItems">
        <a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a> 
        <div class="catalogueItemsText">Bed Frames</div>
    </div>
    <div class="catalogueItems">
        <a href="http://www.dreams.co.uk/beds"><img class="img1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5008/q5uCoV.jpg" /> </a> 
        <div class="catalogueItemsText">Bed Frames</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS part :

```
.catalogue{    padding:0; margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;}
.catalogueItems{display:inline-block;width:16%;}
.catalogueItems a{display:block ;}
.catalogueItems img{width:100% ;}
.catalogueItemsText{width: auto; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(229, 19, 39);font-size:16px;    line-height: 22px;    color:#FFF ;}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    .catalogueItems{display:block;width:50%;}
}
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Just in case, another simpler way, but maybe too modified for your needs : http://jsfiddle.net/y9eo177w/2/

Comment: the code you provided is working but again once open on Iphone is not visualising correctly. Any idea what might cause it?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot ? I don't have an iphone to test it. If the problem is the same (overlay) it's probably a cache problem

Comment: Just one more thing : make sure you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>`, instead it won't be responsive (your iphone will zoom out to fit instead of respecting pixels).